# Turn htop into widget

Tags: fedora, terminal, gnome-shell, htop, wxwidgets

I am a big fan of `htop` and would like to know if it is possible to turn it into a widget? I currently use Fedora 23 with Gnome 3.18.5.

Currently I just open a terminal, resize it so show only the resource bars an top info, select `always on top`, `Always on visible workspace` and hide the menu bar. Is there any way to create a persistent terminal with `htop` that would appear when I login?

If not, any alternative light weight resource monitor you suggest that could be used as a desktop widget?

Comment: Have you looked at conky?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `Conky lua` can be a better option. for you to get a desktop widget. But you need to modify it with `htop`. conky uses `top`.